# Insert each date record for current month in Access table using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am new with VBA programming. I have designed one form in which there is a button. After clicking this button I want to insert record in my table having one date column. The number of dummy record should be equals to number of days in current month. If Month is May 2016 then record will inserted with date  1/5/2016,
2/5/2016.......31/5/2016 like that.

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim currDateTime As Date
    currDateTime = Now()
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_ShipOrders (IDate ) VALUES (" & currDateTime & " )"
    CurrentDb.Execute (strQuery)
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `for...next` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The following expression will give you an integer, the number of days in the current month:

```
Day(DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())+1, 0))
```

This is the zeroth day of the following month, which is the last day of the current month. This expression will still work if moving from December to January.

Store this in a variable, say `lastDay` then use a loop, `For x = 1 To lastDay` to perform the inserts.

Within the loop, this expression

```
DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), x)
```

will give you the dates 1/5/2016, 2/5/2016,.., 31/5/2016.

You should also surround the dates with date delimiters # when inserting. Combine this with ISO formatting of the date `yyyy-mm-dd` (so that months won't be interpreted as days):

```
VALUES (#" & Format(dtValue, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#)"
```

where dtValue is the date you've just formed using the previous DateSerial expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table containing every possible day number

```
[DayOfMonth]

dd
--
 1
 2
 3
...
30
31
```

and then just use a query like this to generate one row for each day in the current month

```sql
SELECT DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), dd) AS IDate
FROM DayOfMonth
WHERE Month(DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), dd)) = Month(Date())
```

To use it as an INSERT query would be

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_ShipOrders (IDate)
SELECT DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), dd) AS IDate
FROM DayOfMonth
WHERE Month(DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), dd)) = Month(Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, see below code and read comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Command0_Click()
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
Dim curDate As Date

'get first day from current date
startDate = GetFirstDayInMonth(Date)
'get last day from startDate
endDate = GetLastDayInMonth(startDate)
'loop through the dates
For curDate = startDate To endDate
    'here call the procedure to insert data
Next

End Sub

'function to return first date in the month
Function GetFirstDayInMonth(dCurDate As Date) As Date

    GetFirstDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(dCurDate), Month(dCurDate), 1)

End Function

'return last date in the month
Function GetLastDayInMonth(dCurDate As Date) As Date

    GetLastDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(dCurDate), Month(dCurDate) + 1, 1 - 1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fancy query that will return a month's dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    10 * Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Id, 
    DateAdd("d",[Id], DateSerial(Year(DateOfMonth), Month(DateOfMonth), 1)) AS [Date]
FROM 
    msysobjects AS Uno, 
    msysobjects AS Deca
WHERE 
    (10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)) < Day(DateSerial(Year(DateOfMonth), Month(DateOfMonth)+1, 0))
```

That said, I would write a loop adding records to a recordset using VBA, not the slow SQL call of yours.