# SQL join count of date ranges to table of calendar dates?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a tblAbsence

```
Name    Start   End
Joe    18-Mar-2018 0800 26-Mar-2018 1830
Mary    19-Mar-2018 0010    19-Mar-2018 2349
Adam    21-Mar-2018 0700    21-Mar-2018 1300
```

Is there a SQL query that would create a new table of dates with the count of people absent that day?

```
Date    Absent
18-Mar-18   1
19-Mar-18   2
20-Mar-18   3
```

I know how to create a recordset from a calendar table and basically rs1.movenext through each date while I Update tblTemp with a count that meets the

```
WHERE tblAbsence.start <= rs1.date AND tblAbsence.End >= rs1.date;
```

but that seems ridiculously repetitive when there is probably some type of JOIN that might work?

Comment: Do you have a calendar table or numbers table?

Comment: Start and End of tblAbsence are DTGs

Comment: You might take advantage of series of dates as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46954816/3527297).

Comment: Thanks but creating the list of dates is not a problem...I'm actually building that tbl from another list.  I am just unfamiliar with how I could join them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of dates, the problem is pretty simple. You can use a subquery to count from your absence list, where the date from your list is between the start and end of absence.:

```
SELECT TheDate, (SELECT Count(Name) FROM Absent WHERE Absent.End > DateList.TheDate AND Absent.Start < DateList.TheDate + #23:59:59#) As Absent
From DateList
```

Where DateList is a list of all dates you're interested in (either from a table, or from Gustav's query)

Comment: getting there but the Query.recordcount = Datelist.recordcount * Absent.recordcount. So if there were only 3 dates in Datelist for ex you would get a recordcount 3x's larger than in Absent

Comment: `SELECT datelist.Date, (SELECT Count(tblAbsence.Name) FROM tblAbsence WHERE tblAbsence.End >= datelist.Date AND tblAbsence.Start <= datelist.Date) AS Absent
FROM datelist, tblAbsence; `

Comment: That's not the SQL I shared. Remove that cross join. It ruins the query. Also, you've removed the `+#23:59:59#`, making absence not count on the last day.

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like below:

```
select rs1.date,count(ta.Name) from Calendar rs1
    join tblAbsence ta on (ta.start<DATEADD(day,1,rs1.date) and ta.end >=rs1.date)
group by rs1.date
order by rs1.date
```

Comment: That's not valid Access (JET/Ace) SQL. The join will fail, and if you fix that, it will prompt you for a parameter (day).

Comment: Actually outer joins are allowed since Access-2013, and there is a ms-access-2013 tag in the posting.

Comment: It's not the outer join. They're allowed since always, as far as I know. It's the multiple comparisons and calculations in a join, without parentheses. You can try it in Access, and you'll see it won't work. Also, `Count(*)` + a `LEFT JOIN` will return 1 where it should return 0.