# Calculate clients per week based on start date and end date in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, group-by

In a MS Access DB I have information about clients' arrival and departure dates. Based on this I would like to calculate the number of clients that will be visiting per week.

Consider the example below. Peter arrives in the first week of January and leaves on the third week (weeks start on Sunday). Mary on the other hand arrives and leaves in the first week.

[image]

I would like the output to be as shown below, with the week number in the first column and the total number of guests in the second.

[image]

What is the best way of achieving this please?

Comment: You want this to be done in SQL or Access?

Comment: Does week one start on 31st December 2017 or 7th January?

Comment: In german week one starts on 01 Jan. 2018

Comment: @twyly.  Was thinking something like `DatePart("ww",[arrival])` [DatePart function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/DatePart-Function-26868A79-5505-4E5A-8905-6001372223FA) would work.  `firstweekofyear` argument might be a bit problematic if OP wants the year to start on a Sunday.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Week 1 starts 31st Dec

Comment: I think `DatePart("ww",[arrival]-Weekday([arrival],1)+7)` will give you the week number.  You may have to join it to a table containing the week numbers 1 to 53 so that it includes all week numbers between arrival and departure date.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with german date format, test with ORACLE. I build some calendar table (tw_test_week) for every week to join it.

```
CREATE TABLE tw_test_client (
 client VARCHAR2(10),
 arrival DATE,
 departure DATE
);

INSERT INTO tw_test_client VALUES
( 'Peter', to_date('01.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'), to_date('11.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'));

INSERT INTO tw_test_client VALUES
( 'Mary', to_date('01.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'), to_date('01.02.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'));

CREATE TABLE tw_test_week (
 weekid INT,
 started DATE,
 ended DATE
);

INSERT INTO tw_test_week VALUES
( to_char(to_date('01.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'),'WW'),
  to_date('01.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'), 
  to_date('07.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY')
);

INSERT INTO tw_test_week VALUES
( to_char(to_date('08.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'),'WW'),
  to_date('08.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'), 
  to_date('14.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY')
);

INSERT INTO tw_test_week VALUES
( to_char(to_date('15.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'),'WW'),
  to_date('15.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'), 
  to_date('21.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY')
);

INSERT INTO tw_test_week VALUES
( to_char(to_date('22.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'),'WW'),
  to_date('22.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'), 
  to_date('28.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY')
);

INSERT INTO tw_test_week VALUES
( to_char(to_date('29.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'),'WW'),
  to_date('29.01.2018','DD.MM.YYYY'), 
  to_date('04.02.2018','DD.MM.YYYY')
);

SELECT w.weekid, COUNT(*) 
  FROM tw_test_week w
  JOIN tw_test_client c
    ON w.started BETWEEN c.arrival and c.departure
GROUP BY w.weekid
ORDER BY w.weekid;
```

Result

```
WEEKID  COUNT
1   2
2   2
3   1
4   1
5   1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I was hoping for something more scalable. With your suggestions if I want to check the count for the next 100 weeks, I would need to manually create 100 records in tw_test_week.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table containing the numbers 1 to 53.  This table in my query is called `WeekNumTable` and contains a single field with each week number listed.

```
SELECT      WeekNum
            , COUNT(WeekNum) AS TotalClients
FROM        WeekNumTable INNER JOIN ClientTable ON 
                WeekNumTable.WeekNum>=DatePart("ww",ClientTable.Arrival-Weekday(ClientTable.Arrival,1)+7) AND
                WeekNumTable.WeekNum<=DatePart("ww",ClientTable.Departure-Weekday(ClientTable.Departure,1)+7)
GROUP BY    WeekNum
```

Your example confused me a little as you list week 3 as having 1 client, while the data table doesn't.

**Edit:** The one problem that I can see with this is that if you do want to look at the next 100 weeks you'll need something to separate the years otherwise week 1 from both years will be lumped together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of queries to obtain this.

First, create a query named *Ten*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM MSysObjects;
```

Then you can create a query, *ClientDays*, that lists all your dates between first arrival and latest departure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100 AS Id, 
    DateAdd("d",[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100,[StartDate]) AS [Date]
FROM 
    Ten AS Ten_0, 
    Ten AS Ten_1, 
    Ten AS Ten_2, 
    (Select 
        Min([Arrival]) As StartDate, 
        DateDiff("d", Min([Arrival]), Max([Departure])) As Days 
    From 
        ClientDates) AS T
WHERE 
    ((([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100)<=[Days]) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_0.N)<=[Days]\1) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_1.N)<=[Days]\10) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_2.N)<=[Days]\100));
```

Use this in yet a query, *ClientWeeks*, to find the week numbers:

```
SELECT 
    Year([Date]) AS [Year], 
    DatePart("ww",[Date]) AS Week, 
    ClientDates.Client
FROM 
    ClientDays, 
    ClientDates
WHERE 
    ClientDays.Date Between [Arrival] And [Departure]
GROUP BY 
    Year([Date]), 
    DatePart("ww",[Date]), 
    ClientDates.Client;
```

Finally, count the clients:

```
SELECT 
    ClientWeeks.Year, 
    ClientWeeks.Week, 
    Count(ClientWeeks.Client) AS TotalClients
FROM 
    ClientWeeks
GROUP BY 
    ClientWeeks.Year, 
    ClientWeeks.Week;
```

Please note, that you will have trouble counting around New Year as you intend to use an inconsistent week numbering method.

The only week number that is unambiguous is the **ISO-8601** system of *yyyy-ww* because the first and/or last week will cross the calendar year boundaries.

Leave a note if you wish to implement this as it cannot be done with native VBA functions; custom functions must be used, but I don't wish to post them here if you will not use them.

Comment: Also see this simple method for [creating a series of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37509312/3527297).